# Function when returning a paragraph python

Tags: python, string, algorithm, paragraph

I´m defining a function to return a paragraph string, but when i return it, and then print it, it returns this:

('      | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j |\n    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n    10|', '  |   |   | ♥ |   |   | ♥ |   |   |  ', '|\n    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n    9 |', '  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  ', '|\n    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n    8 |', '  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  ', '|\n    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n    7 |', '♥ |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | ♥', '|\n    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n    6 |', '  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  ', '|\n    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n    5 |', '  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  ', '|\n    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n    4 |', '♠ |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | ♠', '|\n    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n    3 |', '  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  ', '|\n    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n    2 |', '  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  ', '|\n    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n    1 |', '  |   |   | ♠ |   |   | ♠ |   |   |  ', '|\n    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+')

But instead of returning it, If i print it inside the function. This is the result.

```
  | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
10|   |   |   | ♥ |   |   | ♥ |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
9 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
8 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
7 | ♥ |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | ♥ |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
6 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
5 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
4 | ♠ |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | ♠ |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
3 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
2 |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
1 |   |   |   | ♠ |   |   | ♠ |   |   |   |
--+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

this is the code, i hope it helps

```
tableron=[]
for i in range(10):
    tableron.append([" "]*10)

columnas=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]

def cargar_tablero():
    tablero=[]
    archivo=open("tablero.txt","r")
    for line in archivo:
        line=line.strip()
        tablero.append(line.split(","))
    return tablero

def nuevo_tablero():
    tablero=[["a4","d1","g1","j4"],["a7","d10","g10","j7"],[],["1"]]
    return tablero

def tablero_to_string(tablero):
        lista=tablero[0]
        for m in lista:
            tableron[int(m[1::])-1].pop(columnas.index(m[0]))
            tableron[int(m[1::])-1].insert(columnas.index(m[0]),"♠")

        lista=tablero[1]
        for m in lista:
            tableron[int(m[1::])-1].pop(columnas.index(m[0]))
            tableron[int(m[1::])-1].insert(columnas.index(m[0]),"♥")


        if tablero[3]!= None:
            lista=tablero[2]
            for m in lista:
                tableron[int(m[1::])-1].pop(columnas.index(m[0]))
                tableron[int(m[1::])-1].insert(columnas.index(m[0]),"*")          



        print ("""      | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j |
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    10|"""," | ".join(tableron[9]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    9 |"""," | ".join(tableron[8]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    8 |"""," | ".join(tableron[7]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    7 |"""," | ".join(tableron[6]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    6 |"""," | ".join(tableron[5]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    5 |"""," | ".join(tableron[4]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    4 |"""," | ".join(tableron[3]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    3 |"""," | ".join(tableron[2]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    2 |"""," | ".join(tableron[1]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    1 |"""," | ".join(tableron[0]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+""")


tablero=nuevo_tablero()
tablero_to_string(tablero)
```

Comment: What's your question and can you show your code?

Comment: sorry i just updated it

Comment: The question is how can i make the first output look like the second one, but returning a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your long string is actually not a string, but a sequence of strings. If you pass them to `print`, they all get printed in turn. If you return them, they get turned into a tuple. If you try and print a tuple, you get a different output.

You can return the whole lot as one string by joining it.

```
return ' '.join(["""      | a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j |
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    10|"""," | ".join(tableron[9]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    9 |"""," | ".join(tableron[8]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    8 |"""," | ".join(tableron[7]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    7 |"""," | ".join(tableron[6]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    6 |"""," | ".join(tableron[5]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    5 |"""," | ".join(tableron[4]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    4 |"""," | ".join(tableron[3]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    3 |"""," | ".join(tableron[2]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    2 |"""," | ".join(tableron[1]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    1 |"""," | ".join(tableron[0]),"""|
    --+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"""])
```

Or you could construct it with concatenation instead of commas.

Once you are returning it as one string instead of a tuple, printing it should work fine.

Comment: But join does not work with 21 arguments.

Comment: `join` works if you put `' '.join([x,y,z])` because the arguments are wrapped up into one argument (a list). Hence the square brackets in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

With [terminaltables](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/terminaltables)

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from terminaltables import AsciiTable
table_data=[
['','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'],
['10','','','','♥','','','♥','','',''],
['9','','','','','','','','','',''],
['8','','','','','','','','','',''],
['7','♥','','','','','','','','','♥'],
['6','','','','','','','','','',''],
['5','','','','','','','','','',''],
['4','♠','','','','','','','','','♠'],
['3','','','','','','','','','',''],
['2','','','','','','','','','',''],
['1','','','♠','','','♠','','','',''],
]
table = AsciiTable(table_data)
table.inner_row_border = True
print table.table
```

The output is identical to yours.